# How can I modify $0?

Tags: bash

print_argv0.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $0
```

caller.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
exec -a modified.sh ./print_argv0.sh
```

When run `./caller.sh`, my expect is

```
modified.sh
```

but got

```
<absolute_path_to_cwd>/print_argv0.sh
```

Is there any way to make modify.sh output?

Comment: The process is created with `caller.sh`, when you `exec -a modified.sh ./print_argv0.sh`, you replace the current process with `print_argv0.sh` (see **man bash** under **BASH BUILTINS**, **exec**). If the `-a` argument is provided, then the shell should pass `modified.sh` as `$0` to the executed command (that's not happening). What version of bash and what OS?

Comment: I tested on Ubuntu20.04 and Bash 5.0.16.

Comment: `. /print_argv0.sh` run as `bash . /print_argv0.sh`, the part corresponding to the value set by exec -a is `bash`, and the part retrieved as $0 is `./print_argv0.sh`.
It caused this behavior I think.

Comment: I get the same behavior on `GNU bash, version 5.1.8(1)-release` (Archlinux). That looks to be worth filing as a bug. I don't have an explanation for why what is seen should be expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, `exec -a` can have quite inconsistent behaviour. Had `print_argv0.sh` been a binary file written, for example, in C, then it would have the desired effect.

If you only care about `$0` and know that the executable will always be a Bash script, then you can start a shell and source the script with `-c` option. When you do so, the first argument (other than the inline command) passed to it is placed in `$0`.

```sh
exec bash -c '. ./print_argv0.sh' modified.sh
```